# libGDX : Multi-color text in one label

Tags: java, libgdx

I saw this post [Multi-colored text in libgdx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21306457/multi-colored-text-in-libgdx) but it's not useful specially in new API.

For example: I want to color "libGDX" text like this:
[image]

```
BitmapFont font = new BitmapFont(Gdx.files.internal("fonts/CarterOne.fnt"));
LabelStyle style = new LabelStyle(font, null);
Label label = new Label("libGDX", style);
stage.addActor(label);
```

How can I do this ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can do this easily with the [color markup language](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Color-Markup-Language) that `Label` supports as well.

Make sure to read that article completely, as there are a few little obstacles involved to get it working.

Comment: I didn't found any obstacles :) that's very easy `font.getData().markupEnabled = true;
  LabelStyle style = new LabelStyle(font, null);
  Label label = new Label("[#ff0000]l[#30ff00]i[#1e00ff]b[#fff600]G[#ff00ae]D[][#ff9000]X", style);` 
THANKS A LOT @noone